# Include all libraries in a directory

Tags: makefile

How do includee all libraries from a directory in a Makefile?

Say I want to include all libraries in the directory `/libdir`, how would I do this?

The result should be something like:

```
INCLUDES = -I/libdir/lib1 -I/libdir/lib2 -I/libdir/lib3 ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LIBDIRS = $(wildcard /libdir/*)

INCLUDES = $(addprefix -I, $(LIBDIRS))
```