# lopencv_core not found when using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, makefile, linker

I have opencv3 installed through home-brew and pkg-config can find the linkers too by

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

the outputs contains -lopencv_core, but when I add that in Makefile like this

```
CC=clang++
CFLAGS= -Wall -g -std=c++0x
LFLAGS= -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/bin -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib -lopencv_core

CFILES=blah.cpp
HFILES=blah.hpp
OFILES=blah.o

all:    main

%.o:    %.cpp $(HFILES)                                                                                   
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LFLAGS)

main:   $(OFILES) $(HFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OFILES) -o main $(LFLAGS)
```

it says

```
ld: library not found for -lopencv_core
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How should I link that to gcc?

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096568/include-all-libraries-in-a-directory) to link all OpenCV libraries in `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib`

Comment: can you add the library and symbolic link names with "core" in it from /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib to your question text, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want `CFLAGS` to be the options for compilation and `LFLAGS` to
be the options for linkage, the settings:

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -g -std=c++0x
LFLAGS= -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/bin -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib -lopencv_core
```

are confused.

The `-I path` option is meaningful for compilation and meaningless for linkage. It
tells the preprocessor to search in `path` for header files that you `#include` in
the source code. There will be header files in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include
```

There will be no header files in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/bin
```

just executables, which are irrelevant to building your program. And there will be no header files in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib
```

just static and or dynamic libraries.

The library `libopencv_core` that linker can't find is presumably
in `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib`. The way to tell the
linker to search there for the library is:

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib -lopencv_core
```

So these settings make sense:

```
CFLAGS := -Wall -g -std=c++0x -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include
LFLAGS := -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib -lopencv_core
```

However, to compile and link an `opencv` program you would probably be better
leaving it to `pkg-config` to get the options right:

```
CFLAGS := -Wall -g -std=c++0x $(shell pkg-config --cflags opencv)
LFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-l` option looks in the usual places for the mentioned library. Where and what it looks varies by OS, which you didn't mention. Possibly it can be fixed by adding `-L /usr/local/lib` or some other path to where you know the libraries are.